# Closing socket does not throw exception

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, networking

```
public void run() {
  try {
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

    Object o;
    while ((o = ois.readObject()) != null) {
        //do something with object
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //Log exception
  }
}
```

Calling `socket.shutdowninput()`, `shutdownoutput()`, `close()`, `Thread.interrupt()` all do not throw an exception when using Android 2.2.2 on the Dell Streak, any ideas why this is so?

Comment: Not related to your question but why are you testing for null? Are you writing nulls? Because that's the only way you will ever read one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7933.

Take a look at last three comments.