# socket.getInputSteam.read() does not throw when I close the socket from the client

Tags: java, sockets, exception

I am on windows 7 x64. I am writing a server which opens a thread for every incoming connection - the thread reads from the connection's input stream. The read() should block and throw an exception if the socket is closed(). It does not - just returns -1. If I do not close the connection from the client - just let the client terminate - I get a connection reset as excpected - but if I close() the connection from the client (or just the client's output stream for that matter) read() in the server thread does not throw - just returns `-1`. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29) are pretty clear on this :

> public void close()
>              throws IOException
>
> ```
> Closes this socket.
>
> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will throw a SocketException.
> ```

Help

Working code :

Server :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CloseTest {
    private int port;

    public CloseTest(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    void base_station_activate() {
        ServerSocket baseStationListeningSocket=null;
        try {
            baseStationListeningSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port, 1, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        main_server: while (true) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = baseStationListeningSocket.accept();
                BaseStationClientHandler ch = new BaseStationClientHandler(clientSocket);
                Thread myThread = new Thread(ch);
                myThread.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.exit(1);
            } // main_server
            finally {
//                  baseStationListeningSocket.close()
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
            CloseTest bs = new CloseTest(8082);
            bs.base_station_activate();
        }
    public class BaseStationClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        private BaseStationClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        public void run() {
            String debug_message = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                // read message and respond
                String s = "";
                char x;
                int r;
                server: while (true) {
                    try {
                        while ((r = in.read()) != (int) '%') {
                            if (r == -1) {
                                debug_message = "Stream/socket .closed() - exception not thrown (WHYYYYY ????) by client";
                                System.out.println(debug_message);
                                break server;
                            }
                            x = (char) r;
                            s += x;
                        }
                        System.out.println(s);
                    } catch (SocketException socketException) {
                        System.out.println(socketException.getLocalizedMessage());  //  if connection reset (but not if Stream/socket .closed()) read throws !!!!!
                        debug_message = "socket_reset";
                        break server;
                    }
                    s = "";
                }   //server
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("IOexception in client handler - check if thrown by read");
            } finally {
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client :

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Vector;

public class CloseTestClient {

    public CloseTestClient(int port, String ipAddress){
        Vector<Socket> connections = new Vector<Socket>();
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
                Socket connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress), port);
                connections.add(connection);
                OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
                out.write( ("CONNECT#"+(i+1)+"#1%").getBytes());
                System.out.println("[CloseTestClient SENT]:"+"CONNECT#"+(i+1)+"#1%");
                Thread.sleep(1000); // to be sure the server threads are blocked in the read()
                // connection.close();  // if I comment this out I see the connection reset message from the server when this main terminates
                // commented it out finally and moved the closing at the end to be sure the server threads are blocked in read()
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            // if I comment *for* out I see the "connection_reset" message from the server when this main terminates
            for (Socket c : connections){
                try{
                    c.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("CloseTestClient run !");
        new CloseTestClient(8082,"127.0.0.1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit of documentation you're referring to applies to threads on that machine, not remote threads. If you have thread A read()'ing on socket X, and thread B of the same process closes socket X, then an exception will be thrown for thread A's read call.

When a socket is close()'d on the the local machine, the remote machine can determine that there will be no more data coming over the socket so it returns -1 (see the read() documentation for InputStream). This is what is happening when you explicitly close the connection on the client. The server knows no more data will be coming so read() happily returns -1. There are no exceptional circumstances.

I'm guessing that when you let the client terminate without calling close() on the socket, the JVM or OS is sending a TCP RST instead of closing the connection nicely (sending TCP FIN). This causes the read() call on the server to throw an exception.

Comment: They are on the same machine - the host is `127.0.0.1` - or what do you mean by same machine ?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say the two threads in that example are part of the same process. At least that's how I interpret that documentation. I haven't tested it. I do know that close() will not cause an exception to be thrown on the other end of the socket.

Comment: Can you point me to some docs on that ? You mean that when one closes() the socket from a different process there is no exception ??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/articles/connection_release.html might help a little bit. I'll see if I can dig up something better later. Looking up client/server examples for Java might lead to something useful (I know sun/oracle has some good tutorials).

Comment: Thanks, read it  - so is it expected behavior ? And what says in the close() docs is just very very bad documentation ? Please confirm before I accept this as an answer :) (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043108/closing-socket-does-not-throw-exception) for instance)

Comment: Yes what you are seeing is expected. If one end of the socket calls close(), then the other end's read() will return -1. You should still wrap the call in the exception handler though because if the client machine crashes (i.e., close() isn't called explicitly), you can still get an exception. The docs are still correct, however. You need to differentiate between who is calling close(). If you had another thread on your server that called clientSocket.close(), then your in.read() would throw an exception. The client closing its socket will not cause the server to throw an exception though.

Comment: I added a small bit of code here: http://www.nealc.com/downloads/cli_server.zip  Uncomment the specified line in server.java and you'll see the exception thrown that the docs are talking about.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D It isn't 'very bad documentation'. You didn't call the close() method whose documentation you cited, so your code didn't do what it says and didn't throw an exception. Instead it got a return value of -1 from read(), which is documented to indicate end of stream which in turn indicates that the peer closed the connection. You didn't.

Comment: @EJP : ok - so let's say not newbie friendly docs then - but which `close()` did I call ? or you mean "I" - " the server" ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Nobody documents things that don't happen when you don't do something, otherwise it would be the labour of Sisyphus. I don't know what you mean by 'which close()' or 'I' in the slightest.

Comment: @EJP : you said _You didn't call the close() method whose documentation you cited_ - so I am asking you which close() did I call - or if by _I_ you meant _I, the server_ as opposed to _I, the client_

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D You called a `read()` method, and you got -1 instead of the exception you expected, based on the documentation of the close() method, which you didn't call. The peer called it, at his end, on his socket. The documentation for `close()` that you cited therefore doesn't apply, 'newbie-friendly' or not as the case may be.

Comment: @EJP : _The peer called it, at his end, on **his** socket_ : I thought it's the same socket you see - that's the confusing part. Clear(er) now, thanks

Comment: It's the same connection, with a socket at each end.