# Can't detect disconnect without extra readLine() loop

Tags: java, sockets, loops, timer, while-loop

I am developing a program that uses sockets and currently I have a function in my code that checks for a heartbeat from the client every second.

```
private void userLoop() { // checks for incoming data from client
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socketIn.read(); // check for heartbeat from client

                String userInput;
                while ((userInput = br.readLine()) != null) {
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                ControlPanel.model.removeElement(getUsername());
                ControlPanel.append(getUsername() + " has disconnected.");
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

When a client closes the game via the X button, shutting off their computer, logging out, whatever it may be, I get the message "'username' has disconnected".  This is exactly what I want, however, it only works with the while loop in the code.  The while loop essentially does nothing and I have no idea why it doesn't work with out.

If I remove the while loop and I disconnect using my client nothing gets printed out server sided.

```
String userInput;
while ((userInput = br.readLine()) != null) {
}
```

The above is essentially the dead code that does nothing but without it my program doesn't work the way it should..

Why is the code needed and how can I remove it and still make my program work correctly?

Comment: What is `socketIn`? What is `br`? Are they related?

Comment: What is `br` reading?

Comment: `The above is essentially the dead code`. I dont think its dead. it keeps reading the buffered input until its null which makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Here is the SSCE: http://pastebin.com/eUQrvgsu

Comment: @Ted Hopp, your answer was correct. EJB is wrong. Client or Server, when an InputStream is closed and you try to read from it it will throw an IOException.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. You are reading a byte directly from the stream by all appearances, and throwing it away, even if the method returns -1 indicating end of stream. Then you are reading lines from a BufferedReader. Whatever the intention here. it cannot possibly work. You can't mix buffered and unbuffered I/O on the same socket, or two different buffers either. You should log the exception you're catching instead of just assuming it means end of stream. You might get a surprise.

Comment: @brunoconde I am not wrong. readLine() returns null at end of stream. Check the Javadoc. You're confusing a local close with a peer close. This is a peer close.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your while loop is essentially stalling your program until you no longer receive an input string. It's not dead code; it is just your way of installing a wait.

Otherwise, based on my understanding in the [Timer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29), it only waits one second, which might be too short of a timespan for what you're waiting to capture.

Comment: Why is it too short?  I close the connection client sided, and what I want to happen is the server to remove the player from the online players list.  This works when the while loop is there..

Comment: The method you're using is schedule(TimerTask task, long delay_in_milliseconds). It sounds like you found your answer by changing things to the `br.readLine();`, which means you needed to read more input lines (which is what the while loop was doing).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by changing everything in the try block with

```
br.readLine();
```

Comment: That has the same effect as the loop as far as consuming all the data in the stream, but will just take a little longer. The timer will be doing the looping for you instead.

Comment: That's all I wanted :p  As long as it detects when a player disconnects, it's all good.

Comment: It's pointless. You don't need the timer. The `readLine()` call will block anyway. If the peer isn't sending data the code will only execute once anywa.

Answer (score 0):

There's a saying I've heard about exception handling: "Exceptions should only be used for exceptional situations." A client disconnecting from a server is not exceptional.

Now that I have that off my chest, let's move on. According to this other question,
[socket.getInputSteam.read() does not throw when I close the socket from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334045/socket-getinputsteam-read-does-not-throw-when-i-close-the-socket-from-the-clie)
it sounds like the read call won't throw if you're closing things properly on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the remote socket is closed, `read()` does not throw an Exception, it just returns `-1` to signal the end of the stream.

The following should work without needing to call `readLine()`:

```
    try {
        int ret = socketIn.read(); // check for heartbeat from client
        if (ret == -1) {
            // Remote side closed gracefully
            clientDisconnected();
        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // Timeout -- handle as required
        handleTimeout();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Connection lost due to I/O error
        clientDisconnected()
    }
```

Comment: You're half right. You're correct about using the read() result, but the IOException could be a SocketTimeoutException, which doesn't indicate a lost connection.

Comment: Yes I know, but since the OP is using the exception to detect the "client disconnected" case, I assumed he didn't set a timeout on the socket timeout. Anyway you're right. I'll edit and clarify, thank you for the comment!